# Cannot find ffmpeg when moving the code to a new computer

Tags: ffmpeg, dependencies

I have a code that works on my computer but when I moved it to a new one it doesn't find the ffmpeg dependency.
It happens on these lines of code:

```
    var videoshow = require('videoshow')
    var image = [{path: './screenshot.jpg'}]
    var videoOption = { 
      loop: 10,
      fps: 25,
      transition: false,
      transitionDuration: 0, // seconds
      videoBitrate: 1024,
      videoCodec: 'libx264',
      size: '640x?',
      audioBitrate: '128k',
      audioChannels: 2,
      format: 'mp4',
      pixelFormat: 'yuv420p'
    }
    //call the videoshow library
     videoshow(image,videoOption).save(filename+"_"+"movie.mp4").on('start',function(command){
         console.log("conversion started" + command)
    }).on('error',function(err,stdout,stderr){
         console.log("some error occured"+ err)
     }).on('end',function(output){
         console.log("conversion complete "+ output)
```

It throws an error "Cannot find ffmpeg".
I tried to do npm install or npm install ffmpeg but it didn't help.
I think this happens because I don't know how to make dependencies work on a different computer.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was a problem with videoshow that couldn't find ffmpeg (although it was installed) so I added a these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe": "^1.2.0",
    "ffprobe": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

And I added these lines of code to  the project:

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);
```

And it fixed the problem